# Did the Buffy writers intend for The First to come back?

Tags: buffy-the-vampire-slayer

The First, with its shapeshifting abilities and the army of Bringers, is initially seen in the season 3 episode Amends, and then returns a full 4 seasons later as the final series villain.

Did the writers always intend for The First to reappear in the Buffy storyline?